# Android Sqlite SELECT Query Error on some Android Devices

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, malformed

The following SQL query runs well in almost all Android devices except the Huawei Media Pad P17.0. I would really appreciate if anyone gave me a reason.

```
   cursor = database
                        .rawQuery("SELECT " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_KATEGORIA + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_NGELI
                                + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_UELEKEZI + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_ENTIMOLOGIA
                                + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.MAANA_MAANA + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_WINGI + " , "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_UGA + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_METHALI + " , "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_MSEMO + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_NAHAU + " , "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_FULL + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_MNYAMBULIKO + " , "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_KISAWE + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_IMAGE + " FROM "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.TBL_MAANA + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.TBL_MANENO + " WHERE "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_ID + " = " + SQLDatabaseHelper.MAANA_NENO_ID + " AND "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.MAANA_NENO + " = ? COLLATE NOCASE", new String[] { searchNeno });
```

The Error it returns is ;

> Malformed MATCH Expression :[-searchkeyword] (code 1)

It **occurs** when I search for words that start with a **hyphen** i.e -ake

Any assistance will be very **appreciated**.

Thanks again

Comment: There is no MATCH in this query.

Comment: @CL. Yes . Surprisingly that's the Error it returns.

Comment: Then show the entire stack trace.

Comment: @CL.  ' android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: malformed MATCH expression: [OR] (code 1)'  .

Comment: @CL. It only does that on the Huawei Media Pad P17.0

Comment: This is not the *entire* stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_KATEGORIA + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_NGELI
                                + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_UELEKEZI + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_ENTIMOLOGIA
                                + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.MAANA_MAANA + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_WINGI + " , "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_UGA + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_METHALI + " , "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_MSEMO + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_NAHAU + " , "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_FULL + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_MNYAMBULIKO + " , "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_KISAWE + " , " + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_IMAGE + " FROM "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.TBL_MAANA + " inner join " + SQLDatabaseHelper.TBL_MANENO + " ON ( "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.NENO_ID + " = " + SQLDatabaseHelper.MAANA_NENO_ID + " )  WHERE "
                                + SQLDatabaseHelper.MAANA_NENO + " = ' ? COLLATE NOCASE", new String[] { searchNeno+"'" });
```

Comment: The error still persists. What do you think could be the problem @amit-bhati

Comment: The error still persists. I have been contemplating this for the last 6 days. What do you think could be the problem @Amit